# S3 SignedURL fails

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a signed URL for a GET object request in S3.  I have this code working flawlessly for putting objects in S3 but I can't seem to get it to work for GET.  I sign the URL with this code

```
    //Create the signed url using the company id
func (user *User) signURLForUser(sess *session.Session) (*URLSign, error) {
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    svc.Config.Region = aws.String(os.Getenv("REGION"))
    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
        Key:    aws.String(user.CompanyID + "/" + user.FileRequest),
    })
    var urlSign URLSign
    //urlSign.Size = *out.ContentLength
    str, err := req.Presign(time.Minute * 60 * 24 * 5) //Expire in 5 days
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error signing URL Request")
        return nil, err
    }
    urlSign.URL = str
    return &urlSign, nil
}
```

But when I try to use the URL it returns I get this error:

```
 <Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>X-Amz-Algorithm only supports "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"</Message>
<RequestId>9D7CFB14B195A260</RequestId>
<HostId>
Dgh+SqrHbrdKcbkCYrAj3nObLMAwS7k5+VR1zwC/8ZMS3S4++IAAEXXh3zMZ3CpOAyxX1Kc7Opg=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I've check the IAM permissions, they're set for GetObject.  I can't think of what else I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Here's an example of the URL
For sure:
https://rsmachiner-user-code.s3.amazonaws.com//CFDMP_ServoGear.gcode?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAVEENPDKJRUDZKEVM%2F20180812%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180812T005443Z&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEBoaDIVdv9t408gWWi9vvSLjAaa0pZNA%2BXu83%2FFSyng4XvFdv5%2B7nRB%2FQydMLyi%2BBS84yXqwP6VYn7VlInw4ip1M0lkjHRXQf8OAvQLPrIl%2FQZoTe%2Fy3N6bqhLDOnFVJ3UZzYDQ4%2FbX%2Brc6mvVbkhRsQPiarKBuLYDiOD%2FNoSaItMwI9FsMDknw1qX0Pf%2BZ5La0GmanHrTt9YUI01cIUKJ40No5mKJIwcXw3%2F5QOpUc59rZ2zEzlWP9OXeEwWKp%2Bog5P0v7ABX1lRPsCx4HGEstKhw3ZWmJfQhAcAvhrjmXIMqGNKkaCI5L0ap23jf4GvPMGd4%2BcKIKKvtsF&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=82dfb9b392b5e1ef44c7140259ad884e696b48f8094bdd2d223b8650ebdf59f7

Comment: This isn't permissions-related.  Something is wrong with the actual format of the URL.  Can you share one of them with us?

Comment: I added an edit with one of the URLs.

Comment: I see what the problem is, the & are being replaced with \u.  I just don't have any idea why.

Comment: It's something to do with go's byte to string conversion.  I unmarshaled the json object into a struct and everything looks correct when I log it now.

Comment: Unrelated, but `s3.amazonaws.com/<--this-->/CFDMP_ServoGear.gcode?X-` is going to cause you problems at some point.  S3 object keys should not have a leading slash, but `//` appearing in the URL suggests that you are adding them.  This can eventually cause unexpected/strange/confusing behavior or compatibility issues.  A correct object key is `cat.jpg` or `pics/cat.jpg`, **not**  `/cat.jpg` or `/pics/cat.jpg`... but you need to fix this on the upload side as well as the download side. Better to fix it now than to have to fix it later.

Answer (score 13):

Such issues occur when you are not correctly specifying the algorithm. For me, I was using this url: https://s3_endpoint?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026 
which returned to me the same error. I replaced the \u0026 with & and it worked fine.